# Hibernate SQL Grammar Exception on Select Statement

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

I am getting SQL Grammar Exception on simple select statement here is my products class

```
@Entity
public class products {

    private String Code,Name,Description;
    private double Price;

    @Id
    public String getCode() {
        return Code;
    }
    public void setCode(String code) {
        Code = code;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return Description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        Description = description;
    }
    public double getPrice() {
        return Price;
    }
    public void setPrice(double price) {
        Price = price;
    }
}
```

Here is my query which i am executing

```
public products getProductDescription(String Code)
{

    setSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();

    session.beginTransaction();
    String query = "from products p where p.code=:code";
    Query q = session.createQuery(query);
    q.setString("code", Code);
    System.out.println(query);
    products pr  = (products)session.createQuery(query);
    session.close();
    return pr;
}
```

All The Tables Exist and "from products" query works perfectly but when i insert where clause here it doesn't work

**UPDATE1**

```
public products getProductDescription(String Code)
{

    setSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();

    session.beginTransaction();
    String query = "from products p where p.code=:code";
    Query q = session.createQuery(query);
    q.setString("code", Code);
    System.out.println(query);
    products pr  = (products)session.createQuery(q);
    session.close();
    return pr;
}
```

Error at `products pr = (products)session.createQuery(q);` saying The function createQuery does not support argument of type Query. Quickfix tells me to change it to string

Comment: Try using `code` instead of `Code`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note you should change your property names to start with lower case letter like `code` instead of `Code`. That's required when you are working with a lot of frameworks.

Once you have renamed your properties, try the following -

```
String query = "from products p where p.code=" + Code;
```

---

Also, as @Luiggi suggests in the comment always use parameters instead of concatenating strings. e.g.

```
String query = "from products p where p.code = :code";
```

---

Another advice is to make your class name start with upper case letter. e.g. `Product` instead of `products`.

Finally, your query would look like -

```
 String query = "from Product p where p.code = :code";
 Query q = session.createQuery(query);
 q.setString("code", code);
```

---

**Update**

```
public products getProductDescription(String Code)
{

    setSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();

    session.beginTransaction();
    String query = "from products p where p.code=:code";
    Query q = session.createQuery(query); //query is already created here
    q.setString("code", Code);
    System.out.println(query);

    //delete the line below
    //products pr  = (products)session.createQuery(q);

    //add the lines below
    List<products> l = (List<products>) q.list();
    products pr = null;
    if(!l.isEmpty()) {
        pr = l.get(0);
    }

    session.close();
    return pr;
}
```

Comment: And do not concatenate the Strings, use parameters instead.

Comment: how to use parameters?

Comment: @user1375948 the `Query` interface is very fluent. Check along the methods to see how to use parameters. If you resist to do that, you can check the official documentation as well.

Comment: @user1375948: See the update on how to use the [`Query`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html) api to set the named parameter.

Comment: What's SalesPoint? My suggestion is to change your property names to `code`, `name`, `description`, `price`, and your class name to `Product`. Then use the final query I put in the answer.

Comment: I have fixed that bro but now this error is occurring >>> HTTP Status 500 - org.hibernate.QueryException: Not all named parameters have been set: [code] [from products p where p.code=:code]

Comment: Yes i have set it but still  getting this error. I am updating the query on my question please check it and tell me what's wrong here

Comment: I looked at your update. Remove `products pr  = (products)session.createQuery(query);` and do `List l = q.list();` instead.

Comment: I am guessing that you are creating another query with a second `createQuery(query)` and executing that one instead of the one on which you set the named parameter value.

Comment: Yes just noticed it and changed it but it says createQuery() is not supported with Query parameter